# Is it possible to ignore the Laravel Lang cache temporarily?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I built a translation system for fun which reads all `trans()`/`Lang::get()` calls in my app and presents them along with their current translations in the localisation files in `resources/lang`, so that an admin user can enter new translations which updates a single localisation file on the fly.

Everything works as intended, but there's one minor annoyance: every time the form is sent and the localisation file is updated, the page reloads (through a `redirect()->route()` call, not e.g. `redirect()->back()`), but most of the time, it still displays the old information even though the file has been updated properly.

If I refresh, the changes show up after 0.5-5 seconds, which makes me assume it's a cache issue. So the question is: can I trigger a language cache ignore while I'm in the translation system, or is there another and/or smarter way? I did try sleeping for a couple of seconds, but it made the user experience kind of crappy.

Comment: There is no cache on the language utilities, as you can see by browsing through the code on this repo: https://github.com/illuminate/translation. Have you tried dumping the translation file when redirecting back?

Comment: Thank you. It's not a back redirect, but yes, I have, and it gives me the old contents.

Comment: I have made changes to a language file and can't figure out how to make them take effect. I have cleared all possible laravel caches. How the hell to you tell Laravel to re-read the language files?

Comment: Wish I knew, @PastorBones - I never did figure the issue out.

Comment: I guess it's time to spend 2 hours digging into Laravel to figure out how/why...I'll post an answer when I figure it out.

Comment: Enjoy, mate... Good luck.

Comment: I was making the changes to a file in `/resources/views/lang/` instead of `/resources/lang/`. Now I'm not sure why I have that other lang directory at all :/

Comment: @PastorBones Ah... oops. :/

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue.

I added in my controller sleep and info to extra refresh the page from js.

```
sleep(2);
return back()->with("refresh","yes");
```

and then in my view:

```
@if (session('refresh'))
<script>
    location.reload(true);
</script>
@endif
```

I know it's a stupid solution but it works. If somebody know a better way to do it, write me a comment please.